# Is there any possible way to show the properties of geojson without feature in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

In leaflet, I can visualize the geojson layers using following script;

```
L.geoJSON('district.json', {
    style: myStyle,
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
       layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);     
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

The above code shows the features on the map and also show the `name` properties when clicked on map. But what I want is different. I want to hide the feature of the `district.json` on map, but It should be appear the popup content when I clicked on the `feature` position. I tried following style;

```
var myStyle = {
  fillColor: rgb(0,0,0,0),
  opacity: 0,
  strokeOpacity: 0,
}
```

This will hide the layers, but when I clicked on the map, nothing will popup. Is there any possible styles for this conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change the value of opacity to `0.01` so that the layer will disappear from the map but there still remaining the popup content.
For this change your myStyle variable in following way;

```
var myStyle = {
  fillColor: rgb(0,0,0,0.01),
  opacity: 0.01,
  strokeOpacity: 0.01,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use circle markers as following:

```
L.geoJSON('district.json', {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {color: 'transparent', fillColor: 'transparent', radius: 20});
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
       layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);     
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

This way, you add a transparent, non-visible circle marker for each feature. You can also try different *radius* values that will lead to larger or smaller clickable areas.

Comment: This is not the desire case. Because my data is in polygon. But somehow solve my problem